# HTML5 native drag and drop containment?

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

Is there any way to contain a draggable element (using the native html drag and drop api rather than a library) to the confines of one of its parents? Using Firefox I can drag an element even outside of the browser, into the search bar, etc., which is pretty annoying. Ideally, I'd like the draggable image to be 'stuck' inside a container.

Ie I'm looking for something that mimics the behavior of the jquery UI draggable library https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment

I've tried hiding/showing the drag image on a `dragexit` event, but unfortunately the drag image seems static once its generated?

Comment: Yes same problem happend me also any solution is available native drag and drop containment.